# Change backgroundImage opacity css without changing text in it Opacity

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has an background image set. There is some text in this div as well.

I want

to have full opacity all the time. On mouse over the background image must change from 0.5 to 1 opacity.

```css
 #cover {
   background: url(http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-3.jpg);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   opacity: 0.5;
 }
 #cover:hover {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-12" id="cover">
  <h2>ABC</h2>
  <p>WELCOME USER</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to do??explain

Comment: He would like to have opacity: 0.5 on the background image, but not on the text itself (contained in the same div): See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0mgrt069/

Comment: Thanks for putting this on jsfiddle @Preben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use a div inside a div to serve the background:

http://jsfiddle.net/0mgrt069/9/  (just fixed a typo)

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <h2>ABC</h2><p>WELCOME USER</p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.background{
    background:url(http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-3.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;

}
.background:hover{
   opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding an extra element, why don't you think of using pseudo elements? you could then 'alter' the background opacity on the hover:

Something like:

```
 #cover:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: url(http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-3.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index:-2;
}
```

whilst making your `#cover` have a `position: relative`.

## **Live Demo**

```css
#cover {
  position: relative;
  background: width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#cover:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
#cover:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: url(http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-3.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12" id="cover">
  <h2>ABC</h2>
  <p>WELCOME USER</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. Set the opacity of text to original opacity of image or as per your requirement of opacity value for text.
http://jsfiddle.net/pradyumnaswain/Lpmkq6of/

```css
#cover {
  background: url(http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-3.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#cover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
h2 {
  opacity: 0.5
}
p {
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12" id="cover">
  <h2>ABC</h2>
  <p>WELCOME USER</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your answer is that the "text" also has an opacity. I don't think thats what the author meant. :)

Comment: As the text is inside that div, it tends to change its opacity value as per the div CSS hover property. So you have to set the opacity value of text manually in order to not overridden by hover.

Comment: Text should not change opacity.